# I am trying to swap the string entered by user

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a bash script to swap the words entered by the user.

For example: `hello stack overflow`

Output:  `overflow stack hello`

User can enter any number of words.

Comment: Do you have a *question*? If it's *"how can I do that?"*, it's not appropriate for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
read -ra line                        # read into array
i=${#line[@]}                        # determine length of array
for i in $(seq $((i-1)) -1 0); do    # loop in reverse order 
   echo -n "${line[i]} "             # echo entry at i-position without linefeed
done
echo                                 # linefeed
```

input

```
this is a test
```

output

```
test a is this
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following article explaining the use of "read" in bash:

http://landoflinux.com/linux_bash_scripting_read.html

If you know ahead of time the number of words you will be switching, a simple solution could be something like this. Each word is assigned to a variable specified in your read command:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter two words: "
read one two
echo "first word: $one"
echo "second word: $two"
```

If you need to reverse a list of words in one string, you can take a look at this answer:

[How to reverse a list of words in a shell string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27703776/how-to-reverse-a-list-of-words-in-a-shell-string)