# echo file names in reverse order

Tags: bash, sorting, echo

I would like to list files in reverse order, list of files listed are as below, the purpose is to echo all the file contents into another file.

vcp.status-200.txt
vcp-status-400.txt
vcp-status-500.txt
vcp-status-000.txt

I am currently running below command; **echo** will list all the files and **xargs cat** will append the content of these files into **OutputFile**.

**echo *${USER}*status*.txt | xargs cat >> OutputFile**

**Current Output**

vcp-status-000.txt vcp-status-200.txt vcp-status-400.txt vcp-status-500.txt

**Intended Output**

vcp-status-500.txt vcp-status-400.txt vcp-status-200.txt vcp-status-000.txt

Comment: You can order the files using `ls`, e.g. `USER="vcp"; ls -r "${USER}"-status-* | xargs cat >> OutputFile`. Does that work for your use-case?

Comment: did you read the man page of ls? `ls --help` gives `Sort entries alphabetically if none of -cftuvSUX nor --sort is specified.` and the `-r` option for reversing

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, I would like to echo the list of files contents to a OutputFile.

Comment: ls -r ${USER}-status-* | xargs cat >> OutPutFile worked. Thank you @jared_mamrot

Comment: You're welcome; other options are covered in the linked posts ([How to reverse a list of words in a shell string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27703776/how-to-reverse-a-list-of-words-in-a-shell-string) & [Unix's 'ls' sort by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878249/unixs-ls-sort-by-name))